# Resize and save image

Tags: php, wordpress

Im trying to resize and save an image in WordPress, using the `wp_get_image_editor` with no luck. The image does not get saved, and I get no errors. What am I doing wrong? How would you approach it?

Code

```
$original = 'http://dgli.local.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/IMG_7686.jpg';
if(!file_exists($original)) {
  return;
}

$editor = wp_get_image_editor($original, array());

$result = $editor->resize(300, 300, true);

if(!is_wp_error($result)) {
  $editor->save($editor->generate_filename());
  echo 'success';
} else {
  echo 'error';
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing it's because you need to pass the server path to the image, not the URL.

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Your `$original` variable shouldn't point to the URL, you need to get the actual server path to the file. Use this: `$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir(); $path = upload_dir['path']; $original = $path . '/2020/03/IMG_7686.jpg';`

Comment: Ah, got it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome! Good luck!

Comment: sorry..use 'basedir' instead of 'path'! 'path' returns the current directory WP will use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this as a comment, but think it's worth the answer:

The file path should not be a URL, it should be the server path to the file.

```
// Get the upload directory.
$upload_dir = wp_get_upload_dir();
// Get the base directory.
$path = $upload_dir['basedir'];
// Append the directory to your file name.
$original = $path . '/2020/03/IMG_7686.jpg';

$editor = wp_get_image_editor($original, array());

$result = $editor->resize(300, 300, true);

if(!is_wp_error($result)) {
  $editor->save($editor->generate_filename());
  echo 'success';
} else {
  echo 'error';
}
```

Comment: where was the image saved actually by $editor->save , I mean directory ?

Comment: In this instance, it will save to `/2020/03/` as `IMG_7686-300x300.jpg` You can change the directory by passing in a path change to the [`generate_filename` method](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_image_editor/generate_filename/).